# The time complexity of the leader-follower algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

I'm trying to understand the complexity of the Leader-Follower algorithm. Here is the worst case scenario of the algorithm:

```
public class ScalabilityTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double[] array = new double[5000000];

    for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
            double x = array[j] + array[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println( (System.currentTimeMillis()-oldTime) / 1000 );
}

}
```

I'm assuming that the complexity is O(N*Log(N)), is that correct? The first N part is I'm sure about because of the first loop, however I am unable to be sure about how to calculate the complexity of the inner loop.

EDIT: 
Short information about the leader-follower algorithm: the algorithm is an online clustering algorithm to cluster data streams, where it's not necessary to define the number of clusters. The algorithm accepts a data input and a threshold. The algorithm works as follows:

1- It calculates the similarity of the incoming item with all existing clusters
2- If the similarity between the item and a cluster is above the threshold, then the item is added to the clusters.
3- If not, the algorithm creates a new cluster and assigns the item to this cluster.

From that we can see the worst-case scenario: suppose we have a 1000 elements and suppose for each incoming item it can't finda cluster to assign it, then it will end up with 1000 clusters at the final iteration.

Comment: What is the "leader-follower" algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of this algorithm is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).  To see this, note that the inner loop will run for 0 iterations when i = 0, 1 iterations when i = 1, 2 iterations when i = 2, etc.  If you sum this up for i ranging from 0 to n - 1, you get

> 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n - 1) = n(n - 1)/2 = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

Therefore, the total runtime is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).  You see analyses similar to this one in the analysis of selection sort and (the worst case of) insertion sort, since each of those algorithms does 1 + 2 + ... + n work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please tell me how you found that the summation equals n(n - 1)/2?

Comment: @guckogucko- This is a very famous summation and there are lots of good explanations online.  One simple one is to note that 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = (1 + n) + (2 + (n - 1)) + (3 + (n - 2)) + ... [n / 2 times] = (n + 1) + (n + 1) + ... [n / 2 times] = n(n + 1) / 2.  There are many other proofs of this result, though.

Comment: One other comment, when I run the algorithm, with array of size 10^6, it finishes in less than a second! However I'm only running that exact piece of code above. But when I run it with the real calculations, that takes so much time.

Comment: @guckogucko Perhaps, then, that particular loop is not the part of the algorithm where most of the computing time is consumed... A profiler might help find the actual code where the most time is being spent...

Comment: @guckogucko- Without seeing more of the code, I can't really explain why that is.  You might want to post that as a separate question so that people can look over the code and help you figure out why it runs so quickly.

Comment: @templatetypedef I modified the question and posted the exact code I'm running. It runs in less than a second!

Comment: @templatetypedef I created another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095258/why-this-on2-algorithm-java-code-runs-so-quickly

Comment: @guckogucko I don't think that's the exact code you're running... For one thing, C-style arrays declared as `double[] array = new ...` don't have an `array.length` - this likely won't even compile.

Comment: @twalberg- I believe that the OP is writing Java code, not C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, the answer can be depicted as the following (where ***n = array.length***):

[image]