# Why the output result of this value is always zero?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm running this code, but why the output result of m is always zero here?

This is very strange since m is initialized to 2.

```
public class ScalabilityTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double[] array = new double[100000];
    int p = 2;
    int m = 2;
    for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        p += p * 12348;
        for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
            double x = array[j] + array[i];
            m += m * 12381923;
        }
    }

    System.out.println( (System.currentTimeMillis()-oldTime) / 1000 );
    System.out.println( p + ", " + m );
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the number 12,381,923 significant?  Or did you just button-mash it?

Comment: I just button-mashed it :)

Comment: I just asked a generalization of this question that asks about what happens if you change the start conditions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17096161/501557

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are always multiplying the value of `m` with a number and add to `m`, on the 16th iteration it overflows to become `0`.

In fact, since you are multiplying the number with an odd number then add it to the original, you are multiplying it with a even number, which make the trailing `0` bits moves at least one step left, thus it ends with `0`:

```
1 1011110011101110111001000 24763848
2 1111011100110010111011000100000 2073654816
3 1111111111111101111010010000000 2147415168
4 10010100011000001100001000000000 -1805598208
5 10010010100010001100100000000000 -1836529664
6 10001011110000100010000000000000 -1950212096
7 1110010101001001000000000000000 1923383296
8 1001100000100000000000000000 159514624
9 1010011110010000000000000000000 1405616128
10 10001110001000000000000000000000 -1910505472
11 1010100100000000000000000000000 1417674752
12 1000010000000000000000000000000 1107296256
13 11001000000000000000000000000000 -939524096
14 100000000000000000000000000000 536870912
15 10000000000000000000000000000000 -2147483648
16 0 0
```

Comment: i suspect it's the overflow too, but it wouldn't go to 0, would it?  it should go to  -2,147,483,648

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found.

Comment: That is a beautiful explanation.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an observation: as soon as `m` reaches 0, executing

```
m += m * 12381923;
```

Will keep `m` at 0.

I wrote a program to output the values of `m` as it goes, and here's what I found:

```
2
24763848
2073654816
2147415168
-1805598208
-1836529664
-1950212096
1923383296
159514624
1405616128
-1910505472
1417674752
1107296256
-939524096
536870912
-2147483648
0
Converged after 16 iterations.
```

For reference, here's the source:

```
public class Converge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 2;
        long counter = 0; // Unnecessary, but I didn't know how many iterations we'd need!

        while (m != 0) {
            System.out.println(m);
            m += m * 12381923;
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println("Converged after " + counter + " iterations.");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `int` value overflows. The following [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) shows that the maximum value of an `int` is 2,147,483,647 and by the time the sixteenth iteration occurs, `m` is greater than this value and hence it overflows.

Comment: But even if it overflows, it should wrap back around to a negative number.  That wouldn't make it 0.